# Error in glmmTMB when fitting mixed model with interactions between two categorical variables

Tags: r, mixed-model, interaction, glmmtmb

my mixed models contain several categorical variables with a lot of unique levels, so model matrix for fixed effects is ​​very sparse. I use `glmmTMB` package that handles X and Z matrices as sparse. This significantly reduced RAM usage during fitting the model.
The `glmmTMB` package is great, but there is one problem for me (maybe I'm missing something):
when I use **interactions between a numeric variable and a categorical variable** (as FE), the model is fitted **without errors**.
For example, this model works well:

`fit = glmmTMB(Y ~ 0 + num1:factor1 + num2:factor1 + factor2 + (0 + num3|subject) + (0 + num4|subject) + (1|subject),  model_data, REML = TRUE, sparseX=c(cond=TRUE))`.

But when I use any **interactions between two categorical variables** i.e. the formula looks like this:

`fit = glmmTMB(Y ~ 0 + num1:factor1 + factor3:factor1 + factor2 +  (0 + num2|subject) + (0 + num3|subject) + (1|subject),  model_data, REML = TRUE, sparseX=c(cond=TRUE))`,

I get the following error:

`iter: 5  Error in newton(par = c(beta = 1, beta = 1, beta = 1, beta = 1, beta = 1,  :  Newton failed to find minimum. In addition: Warning message: In (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  : NA/NaN function evaluation outer mgc:  NaN  Error in (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  :  gradient function must return a numeric vector of length 4`.

At the same time, in mixed model theory, interactions between two categorical variables are valid.
Moreover, such model (with interactions between two factors) is successfully fitted with Julia `MixedModels` package.

Could you help me, please, to understand root of this error?
Is there a way to avoid it in a model with interactions between two categorical variables?
Why does such models work with `Julia MixedModels` and not work with `glmmTMB`?